# Xamarin.forms and immediate mode graphics

Tags: ios, graphics, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

Does anybody know how to draw immediate mode graphics into a xamarin.forms view?

I need to draw some app specific graphics into a form. I've been googling and looking at examples for a lot of the day. I know about Renderers. I can almost do it, but ViewRenderer can't be easily subclassed (unless I'm missing something), and I can't find an existing view subclass that is suitable.

Comment: Are you trying to do this in a portable way (i.e., same code works on Android, iOS, Windows Phone)?

Comment: Indirectly.... I create a sort of "view model" which makes graphics calls against a portable graphics interface. There are concrete implementations per platform. I needed some way of instantiating the concrete implementations, and that is, of course, OS-dependent. I'll supply some details later...

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes my own stupidity and thickness surprises even me.

The answer is to create a concrete, OS-dependent View for each platform. Then create a ViewRenderer implementation for each platform.

The platform-specific ViewRenderer<...> then instantiates the platform-specific view. And we're off to the races.

There are minor details, such as how to communicate or acquire view size and parentage, but at least those are known problems.

So, you have the following components:

A MyXamarinFormsView, which sub-classes Xamarin.Forms.View. MyView doesn't actually have to contain any significant logic. Think of it as a placeholder.

For each platform:

A MyXamarinFormsViewRenderer : ViewRenderer<MyXamarinFormsView, MyPlatformSpecificView>

Add the following attribute instance to each ViewRenderer, after any using statements and before the namespace declaration (if there is one):

[assembly:ExportRenderer( typeof( MyXamarinFormsView ), typeof( MyXamarinFormsViewRenderer ) ) ]

A MyPlatformSpecificView : platform-specific View (e.g. UIView for iOS)

Put the graphics-specific code in each platform-specific view subclass.

I'm not certain if this is the official/correct way of doing it, but it does appear to work for me.

Comment: No, you got it right. Congratulations on answering your own question!